# Regular Expression on Filename

Tags: c#, regex

I have a dwg file with a filename of SMITH 3H FINAL 03-26-2012.dwg and I'm trying to find the right Regular Expression for validation purposes because I will have 100's of files weekly I need to verify the format of the filename is correct.  I know very little about Regular Expressions and I have some code I found below but it is not passing as valid.  If I'm reading the first line correctly, then is it expecting a comma in the filename and that's why it's not passing as valid?

```
string filenamePattern = String.Concat("^",
                                                   "([a-z',-.]+\\s+)+",  // HARRIS, SMITH 
                                                   "(\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}){1}\\s+",  // 09-06
                                                   "([a-z]+\\s)*",  //
                                                   "((\\#?\\s*(\\d(\\s*|,))*\\d*-\\d+-?H?D?\\d*?),*\\s+(&\\s)*)+",  // #5,6-11H & #4,7,8-11H2, etc
                                                   "([a-z()-]+\\s)*",  // CLIP-OUT (FINAL)
                                                   "(\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}(-\\d{2}|-\\d{4})){1}",  // 05-11-2009
                                                   "\\.dwg", // .dwg
                                                   "$");
            RegexOptions options = (RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Regex reg = new Regex(filenamePattern, options);
            if (reg.IsMatch(filename))
            {
                valid = true;
            }
```

Comment: What validation criteria do you need?

Comment: @Robert-  The Filename will just have 4 sections so for SMITH 3H 02-26-2012.dwg the first section is the name "SMITH" and it can contain multiple names only seperated by a space or hyphen (SMITH-RODGERS), second section will always have a number followed by a H, third section is a date, last section is file type ".dwg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comments on other answer, have a try with:

```
^[a-z]+(?:[ -][a-z]+)*\s+\d+H\s+[a-z]+\s+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\.dwg$
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^[a-z]+(?:[ -][a-z]+)*\s+\d+H\s+[a-z]+\s+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\.dwg$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ -]                     any character of: ' ', '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  H                        'H'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  dwg                      'dwg'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @M42-  Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.  Everyone has some good insight but this was the best explanation that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
// This checks for name"(\w)", then space, then 3H (\w{2}), 
// this will only search for two characters, then space
// then date in the form mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\w*)\s(\w{2})\s(\w*)\s(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\.dwg");
if(reg.IsMatch(filename))
{
    valid = true;

}
```

You would also be able to get each group. Note, that I didn't have the regex to validate the proper class period (or what I assume is class period, "#5,6-11H & #4,7,8-11H2, etc" part). This will provide a basic framework and then you can pull that group and do the checking in the code. It provides a cleaner regex.

EDIT:

Based on what @DaBears needs, I have come up with the following:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\w*|\w*-\w*|\w*\s\w*)\s(\w{2})\s(\w*)\s(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\.dwg");
if(reg.IsMatch(filename))
{
    valid = true;

}
```

This will match for a last name, a hyphenated name, or a space last name and provide whatever they have in a group.

Comment: @Jetti-  This looks great.  Where you are checking for the name using "(\w)" and then a Space can it also allow for a hyphen?  I'm only wanting a Space or Hyphen to pass validation.

Comment: @DaBears Can you provide a generic sample of what you want it to do like you did with the HARRIS example in your original post? That way I can for sure get it working instead of making an assumption on what you mean.

Comment: @Jetti-  I apologize as I should have been more clear.  The Harris example is code I found and the SMITH example is what I'm needing.  So for example in SMITH 3H FINAL 03-26-2012.dwg a proper Filename can be SMITH 3H FINAL 03-26-2012.dwg or SMITH RODGERS 3H FINAL 03-26-2012.dwg or SMITH-RODGERS 3H FINAL 03-26-2012.dwg.  Incorrect example could be SMITH, RODGERS 3H FINAL 03-26-2012.dwg or SMITH FINAL 03-26-2012.dwg

Comment: Because I'm all about teaching someone how to 'fish', I'd recommend these 2 links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx

Comment: Also this is a great Regex test tool if you're writing a lot of RegEx, I tend to use it from time to time to validate my RegEx: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: @crlanglois thanks for the link. I like to use http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html for testing my regexs.

Comment: @Jetti-  I just now saw your latest post and this is great.  I had already accepted M42 below but both of y'all helped me.  I wish there was a way to accept both answers

Comment: @DaBears glad you were able to figure out your problem